# How to add configurable product to category without including simple products?

Tags: magento-2.1, category-products

When I assign a configurable product to a category, all of its simple products are also assigned to the same category. The product list view will display only the base configurable products (as desired). But the layered navigation's product count will include the simple products.

As a result, the number of products displayed in the list view does not match the product count shown in the layered navigation.

Is it possible to add a configurable product to a category, without including the simple products? For now, I've been manually removing the simple products from each category, but this won't scale as more products are added.

## Update

I attempted two tests based on the feedback from Alex and Pmclain. I still ran into the issues where either the layered nav product count is incorrect, or the configurable product doesn't show up at all. Any suggestions?

### Creating a product with "not visible individually"

[image]

#### RESULT

[image]

1. Configurable and simple products are set to `not visible individually`
2. Configurable product associated with the category
3. Configurable product **does not appear in product list** because visibility is set to `not visible individually`.

### Creating a product with `visibility` set to `catalog,search`

[image]

#### RESULT

[image]

1. Configurable product's visibility is set to `catalog,search`
2. Simple products visibility set to `not visible individually`
3. Configurable product shows up in the product list, and simple products do not appear (which is good).
4. Layered navigation count **still includes simple products**.

Comment: What's the visibility attribute of the simple products set to?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set, for associated simple products, the visibility to “Not Visible Individually”, instead of "Catalog, Search"